# Need to combine "Sudo" and "ScpTo" examples of JSch

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I'm unsuccessful with combining "Sudo" and "ScpTo" cases.

I noticed, that both work through "exec" channel.

Clean "ScpTo" case finishes with "Permission denied" message.

"Sudo" case

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -S -u <supervisor> whoami");
```

works fine.

When I connect to my server through FarManager I write server option:

```
sudo su -l <supervisor> -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Also, I can run usual SFTP client like this:

```
sftp -s 'sudo su -l <supervisor> -c /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server'  "usual user"@"host"
```

and give `put` command.

But such option (`-s`) is not implemented in JSch.

How can I configure my case (Sudo & ScpTo) with JSch?

Answer (score 0):

In [`ScpTo.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html), there's this code:

```
String command="scp " + (ptimestamp ? "-p" :"") +" -t "+rfile;
```

Change that to:

```
String command="sudo su -l <supervisor> -c scp " + (ptimestamp ? "-p" :"") +" -t "+rfile;
```

Comment: now it answers -1 in checkAck(in) { int b = in.read();} after             channel.connect();

Comment: Did you check server-side log for any error messages?

Comment: I have no full access to that server and ssh process, I can't check server-side logs now. Can I do something else?

Comment: Try the command (`sudo su ... -c scp ...`) from SSH terminal and see what it outputs. Ideally try this without TTY.

Comment: As expected: `Sorry, user 'usual user' is not allowed to execute /bin/su -l 'supervisor' -c scp -p -t .. as root on ...`. How can I improve JSch and implement `-S` option for Sftp case? It seem not so hard for me.

Comment: So you can run `sudo su ... sftp-server`, but you cannot run `sudo su ... scp`?